# List manipulation with prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a query that gives back the following:

```
sky([1,2,3,4,5,6],X). 
X = [1,3,5,2,6,4]
```

That is, it takes out every other element of a list, and does the same on the remaining list and puts everything together.

This is my code so far.

```
sky([X|Y], Skied):-
    split([X|Y],Z1),
    split(X,Z2),
    sky(Z2,Z3),
    append(Z1,Z3,Skied).

sky([],[]).

split([X,_|T], [X|R]):-
    split(T,R).

split([X|[]], [X]).
split([],[]).
```

Can someone explaint o me why it wont work and the process behind it, like a visual guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, instead of `split(X,Z2)` you need to write `split(Y,Z2)`. That's because X is a single element and `split(X,Z2)`  will return `[X]`, which if I understood correctly  isn't what you want. You need to write `split(Y,Z2)` to take the even elements (or in your description every other element) and call `sky(Y,Z3)` to do the same recursively. So the new version is:

```
sky([X|Y], Skied):-
    split([X|Y],Z1),
    split(Y,Z2),
    sky(Z2,Z3),
    append(Z1,Z3,Skied).

sky([],[]).

split([X,_|T], [X|R]):-
    split(T,R).

split([X|[]], [X]).
split([],[]).
```

Some examples and output:

```
?- sky([1,2,3,4,5,6],X).
X = [1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4] ;
false.
?- sky([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],X).
X = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 8] ;
false.
```

Comment: But what if the list is longer? That would produce tje wrong result since we wont take out every other element from the remaining list etc The desired output is different than yours

Comment: Now i saw that you wanted [1,3,5,2,6,4] but it is not clear what you want in your description .Could make it more clear what you're asking and maybe giving another example??

Comment: Say we have the following list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] the output should be: [1,3,5,7,9,2,6,4,8]. Every other element of the list and of the remaining list and of that remaining list... Etc should be taken out and in the end put together. Does this makse sense? It feels that im bad at explaining :s

Comment: What do you mean every other??? other from what?? What element are you keeping each time and you take out every other?I maybe understand what you ask I will try it...

Comment: I am keeping the first and skipping the second keeping the third skipping the fourth etc... from the original list. Then from the remaining list I am keeping the first and skipping the second keeping the third and skipping the fourth etc... Then from the remaining I am doing the same untill i reach an empty list

Comment: Thanks :) could you please explain why this works? The process I mean. How does prolog know what to append each time?

Comment: It is simple for example L=[1,2,3,4,5,6], first split return Z1=[1,3,5],and Z2=[2,4,6], calls sky'(Z2,Z3) where it calls split returning Z1'=[2,6] Z2'=4 and calls sky''([4],Z3') which returns [4] so for sky' it append([2,6],[4],[2,6,4]) and it returns it to first call in Z3 so finally it appends([1,3,5],[2,6,4],[1,5,7,2,6,4]) where it returns Skied=[1,5,7,2,6,4]. Note that I used above sky' to denote the second call of sky and sky'' for third,similarly Z1'.....just to be more easy to understand the order of calls...